# Is Edward Weevil really the son of Whitebeard?

Tags: one-piece

Edward Weevil was introduced as Whitebeard's biological son, but everyone who was part of the Whitebeard Pirates refused to believe him, claiming that they were the only sons of Edward Newgate.

Is Edward Weevil really telling the truth about being Whitebeard's son? Are there any clues as to who his father is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no proof on the claim that **Edward Weevil** is **Whitebeard's son**.

Weevil **self-proclaimed** himself to be his son and his mother supported this theory by **self-proclaiming** to be "Newgate's lover". It is also unknown why did the WG accepted him into the Seven Warlords ranks and if they only acted on this rumor or have some hidden proof of his claims.

Comment: Whether or not Weevil is actually related to Whitebeard was probably unimportant to the WG when they made him a Warlord. He was already acting in their interests before his appointment hunting down Whitebeard's former crew and allies (which include accomplished new world crews) with brutal efficacy. Dropping his huge bounty and thus allowing the simpleton to act with fewer obstacles would've seemed a good call. It doesn't hurt that at a glance you might think "ehhh... he might be related to Whitebeard?"

Comment: @Gatchwar Sure, but since it was in the NW, Weevil wouldn't need any WG support for him going on a rampage against other pirate crews. That is why I said that maybe the WG knows something more then the rest.